# Irish Snap: Variant Rules

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, card-games

## Introduction

Recently, me and a couple of my friends decided to play some cards, and one of them suggested the game 'Irish Snap', which was the inspiration for this challenge. However, I later learnt that the game has a lot of different rules that you can play with, some of which are listed  [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slapjack#Irish_Snap). The rules that are in this challenge aren't currently listed on that page, hence the name, 'Variant Rules'

## The Challenge

Given an array of 3 cards, output a truthy or falsey value depending on if they make a valid snap in a game of Irish snap.

## Input

The input will be an array of 3 numbers, ranging from 1-13 inclusive, with 1 representing an ace, 11 representing a jack, 12 representing a queen and 13 representing a king. The input can be in any order of top, middle, bottom.

## Rules

The 4 different criteria for if cards make an Irish snap are:

- The top and middle cards are the same
- The top and middle cards have a difference of one
- The top and bottom cards are the same
- The top and bottom cards have a difference of one

If any of these criteria are met, you must output a truthy value. As well as this, for the two criteria that require the cards to have a difference of one, it 'wraps around', meaning that an ace and a king are considered to have a difference of one, and vice versa.

## Test Cases

```
Input (Bottom, Middle, Top) -> Output
1 13 7 -> False
1 4 13 -> True
9 3 6 -> False
8 9 7 -> True
2 6 5 -> True
12 5 11 -> True
10 4 8 -> False
12 13 7 -> False
9 7 10 -> True
7 3 1 -> False
4 2 3 -> True
```

Comment: Can we take the cards seperately? Or take input as `top, [middle, bottom]`?

Comment: sure, you can do both. changed the question to reflect that

Comment: Can we invert the output, i.e return False for valid snaps and vice versa? How about a test case where both middle and bottom are valid?

Comment: Yeah, you can invert the output. Also, added that test case

Comment: Must the output values be consistent or could we, for example, output `0` for `false` and any other integer for `true` or, even, any negative integer for `false` or any positive integer for `true`?

Comment: Yeah, output doesn't have to be consistent. I'm pretty sure there's a couple of answers using that already

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 16 bytes

```perl6
3>(*-(*|*)+1)%13
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3NCoJQFIT39ylmU3g1seMtfxKtVQ8Q7aqF0DUCtVBaRPbsdizSaDnzfcxcdZV7bXHHOEPcqsQwbcNsTGmRHJFqI5FdKhj5udS1xEMArK5KxCgWJ2d/tJyIuzq9Y5kZzW4zOTCV4tkSSMGHnWCd5rUWhFnXcN5WNy1CKHgDDRB@5Dd0Gc37RC4HoiFPeSr4WXb/rroplr6@z1fU0xc)

Anonymous whatever lambda that takes input as `top, middle, bottom` and returns a Junction that evaluates to True or False

Comment: Too bad whitespace is required before `<`, this was the perfect chance to have a heart smiley.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 38 bytes

```python
lambda x,y,z:{x-y,x-z}&{0,1,12,-1,-12}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7LCsIwEEX3fsWsJIFbyKRqquCfuGmRolCbUrrog357nLa4MAqzOvcxtxm6h6/TUF5vocpfxT2nHgPGy9QnA/pknPeTAYMtEpazc2jaZ92p2ndUKgdOwVrvNlh4X6lSCaMDSPhH2NwnkCjn2O6EgTId8yNIEvaHM4NEYxv3Z9tbE2HpXxYt/qjIgNw66DvA6073ZyevWIc3)

Returns a non-empty set (truthy) if valid, empty set (falsey) if not. Takes input in order top-middle-bottom, but can be rearranged for same code size.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
α12%ß!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9o4Jbw/9xGQyPVw/MV/@v8j4421FEwNI7VUTCP5QJzTGLBAkCOpY4CSMIMxLbQUbCEKTICiekomII1GIEYQB2GYJ4BRL8FTAphsiWIBgoYgDjmEJMNYwE)

Takes inputs as `[middle, bottom], top`.

```
α        # absolute difference
 12%     # mod 12
    ß    # minimum
     !   # factorial
```

Only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E. 0! and 1! are both 1, while no other number has a factorial of 1.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 12 bytes

```
1 e.2>12||@-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DRVS9YzsDI1qahx0/2typSZn5ANlbRUMFQyNFdIUzCEihmARE6CAoTFCjaUCSIkZQokFUAhFj5GCGVDAFMkQIwVTkCmGSDYZgA22UEASMsKw3VLBHKTPAEmVOdh6w/8A)

Taking bottom middle as left arg, top as right arg.

## original answer taking input as one list

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 24 bytes

```
1 e.2>#:@3 5(12||@-/)@#]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY2xCsJAEAV7v2IwRQyYmL3zkngQORCsrOytJEFs/IH8@7mixR0W2wyz855x3ZQzo6dkS4vXqxtO18s5ClNjjoUPFrcRsyyh3lWhuMVqNd0fLzVHZgSx9F8iP7JXljoHLF2qDIqyH0OHyyIGh0i21Gp4IEPmb13DHzO1ep2X@AY)

- `#:@3 5` The numbers 3 and 5 in binary are `0 1 1` and `1 0 1` which are the masks for the middle/top and bottom/top cards respectively
- `(12||@-/)@#` We filter the input with those masks, take the abs value of the 
  resulting differences, then the remainder when divided by 12 (for the ace-king case)
- `1 e.2>` are either of the resulting numbers less than 2, ie, 0 or 1?

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 29 bytes

Takes input as `([bottom, middle])(top)`.

The output is inverted.

```javascript
a=>c=>a.every(n=>(n-c)/2%6|0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdDNCoJAFAXgfU9xN@FcSHM0/xbjsidoZy6GaYxCZkJLCHr3aUYICrXt/eCcw73ygfeiu9zuvtInaRpmOCsFK3kgB9k9iWIlUb7AbbROXyEaoVWvWxm0@ky8as/bXtYerr7PDamAboDGNRLIcIrFBmDEdIo0tLhzmM9g9C82@8RSiz/qHVV16B5LS8c@Gs9E5haLpT47BlKHyfxSSFwsXXhA5jBENG8)

---

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>37</s>  30 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Grimy*

Takes input as `([bottom, middle])(top)`.

```javascript
a=>c=>a.some(n=>(n-=c)*n%72<2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdDLDoIwEAXQvV8xG0NreBXklViWfoE7ZNHUYjTYGlB/v1KMEYMQt5MzvXd6Zg/W8uZ0vTlSHYSuqGY05zRnbqsuAkmaI@lQjldymQSbAGuuZKtq4dbqiKxiy@pWlBZeDMcVKoDYQMISI0gwBs@DHo5UZgP0Kp5RxO/U2qh0TgV/JSbvRDJUX8zay2LX3KfO6quQ8LVu3AilHcoGTX6iri7EBkXTyNwEkYkjMy@ZT0wM8j9IPwE)

Comment: `%144` could be `%72`

Comment: @Grimy Thanks! FWIW, `%13` would also work.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 12 bytes

```
›²⌊﹪↔⁻Ｅ²ＮＮ¹²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMO9KDWxJLVIw0hHwTczLzO3NFfDNz@lNCdfwzGpWAMoVAokEwtA8p55BaUlfqW5SUDlmprofKCAoRGQ0rT@/99QwUTB0Pi/blkOAA) Port of @Grimy's answer. Takes input as three separate values bottom, middle, top, and outputs using Charcoal's default Boolean format of `-` for true, nothing for false. Explanation:

```
 ²              Literal 2
›               Is greater than
  ⌊             Minimum of
    ↔            Absolute value of (vectorised)
      Ｅ²Ｎ       First two numeric inputs as a list ([bottom, middle])
     ⁻          Minus (vectorised)
         Ｎ      Third input (top)
   ﹪            Modulo (vectorised)
          ¹²    Literal 12
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

Takes input as `[bottom, top, middle]` or `[middle, top, bottom]` (both work).
Outputs `[]` (Falsy in Pyth) if there's no valid snap, a non-empty array otherwise.

```
f>2%.aT12.+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P83OSFUvMcTQSE/7//9oQyMdcx3TWAA)

If a consistent truthy/falsy value is required, add `.A` in front for +2 bytes. Then output will be `True` or `False`.

### Explanation

```
  f             # Filter on lambda T:
   >2           # 2 > 
      .aT       #     abs(T)
     %   12     #            % 12
           .+   # the list of deltas (difference between consecutive elements)

.A (if required)# Any truthy values in the above list?
```

Edit: -1 with a different approach

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-ap`, 31 bytes

```perl
$t=<>}{$\|=abs($t-$_)%12<2for@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lxNbGrrZaJabGNjGpWEOlRFclXlPV0MjGKC2/yMHt/38TBSMuQ@N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/usmFgAA)

#### Input:

```perl
bottom middle
top
```

Actually, the order of the middle and bottom doesn't matter.

#### Output:

`0` for false; `1` for true

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ạ%12ṠƑ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hroWqhkYPdy44NvH////RJjoKRrH/jQE)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>47</strike> 43 bytes

```c
f(b,m,t){return(1<<t-m|1<<t-b)&0x80101003;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc7NboMwDAfwM36KvzIVESmdcOkHLXS77Ql23AVCukaCbIKgTer67CygHaZYim39bFmv37WeHqzT7dgYlINv7Mfj9Wm6JLXqlJe33vixdwmXpV93P8tXyzj9zlMOL82K@2SdR1dZl0jcKJqrWqFT8AVFX1fbmmTQlbskYtVgiTcnFOKA4qBiL3E@I5MURZ99mP4HT1gNC/5bqDDftaQSzxCv/WgEThAvVTsYIQu6TwzOcCDGNiR0RIY95TiG1gZ77Ig32IGZOA0in8vFBwBO6RA80y8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
d_aV <2
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ZF9hViA8Mg&input=WzEsMTNdCjc)

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL 2008, 40 bytes

```sql
PRINT 1/-~abs((@-@2)%12/2*((@-@3)%12/2))
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1095920/irish-snap-variant-rules)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
I%12ỊẸ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99T1dDo4e6uh7t2/P//31DH0FjHBAA)

A monadic link taking the list of `[middle, top, bottom]` as its argument and returning `1` for snap and `0` for no snap.

Answer (score 0):

## [R], 23 bytes

takes input as a=c(bottom,top,middle):

`any(abs(diff(a))%%12<2)`